# Is it possible to clone or save/restore engine state in Jint?

Tags: c#, jint

I've got relatively long initial code and then I use the engine to execute a single statement which can affect engine state. I would like to speed things up by not re-executing initial code all the time.

Would it be possible to:

- quickly clone the instance of engine with it entire state or
- save and restore quickly engine state?

  ```
  private void RunScript()
  {
      var engine = new Engine();

      //Please note I am executing this only once:
      engine.Execute(@"
          var globalCounter = 0;
          var increaseCounter = function() { globalCounter++; return globalCounter; };
          ");

      //What I need:
      //engine.MagicallySaveState();

      var result1 = engine.Execute("increaseCounter()").GetCompletionValue().AsNumber();
      //result1==1

      //What I need:
      //engine.MagicallyRestoreState();

      var result2 = engine.Execute("increaseCounter()").GetCompletionValue().AsNumber();
      //result2 should be still 1 and not 2 if Save/Restore works;

  }
  ```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer properly without code.

Comment: @Sefe Please find a sample code.